# Given two arbitrary interpolated curves, color them based on relative values

Tags: d3.js

I have two curves, each defined by interpolating over a set of (x,y) values using d3.svg.line.  I would like one line to be red whenever it's below the other, and green when above.  Like so:

[image: lines]

How can this be done?

Comment: Why? Because it's hard to tell if one line is above/below the other??

Comment: Depends on your definition of "easy" -- if you mean "is there an option I can set to get this" then the answer is no. You would have to implement this yourself.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff question edited to be clearer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Difference](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3894205) chart in their examples, it is quite similar to what you want and may satisfy you're criteria. If not I imagine you can adapt it quite easily to suit you're needs.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with this is that you cannot assign more than one colour to a path directly. So you have two main choices.

- Split the line into segments. Each segment could have a different colour.
- Use a gradient. The transitions between the colours would be zero-width.

In either case, you will have to calculate the points where the lines cross over yourself. If your lines are specified as functions, this is easy enough to do with some algebra. If you have only points and want to interpolate between them, it's a bit trickier.

Once you have the points where the lines cross over, it's simply a matter of setting the path/gradient ends accordingly.

Comment: thanks for your answer, that was the approach that came to my mind and it seemed overly complex.  I'm going to see how mbostock did it in Ian's example, since that's perfect for me needs.

Comment: I don't think that this example is applicable in your case, as it doesn't colour the path, but an area defined by the path.